# Calculate integral of a closed curve without Green's Theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I used Green's Theorem to calculate the integral of this curve, I got $4i\sqrt{2}$ . However, I also want to calculate it through the definition of the integral $\int_{\gamma}{\bar{z}}dz$, by splitting the line segments and assigning bounds. Can someone please help me out?

For Green's Theorem, I did $\frac{1}{2} \int_{2e^{-i\pi/4}}^{2e^{i\pi/4}}{(2cos\theta*2cos\theta - {2sin\theta*(-2sin\theta))d\theta}}$ = $4i\sqrt{2}$.

Am I headed in the right direction, also am I applying Green Theorem properly? Of course, both answers should be equivalent.

[image]

Comment: You Green's result is wrong. Somewhere in you calculation, you have 1) forget the $i$ in front of $d\theta$, 2) replace an integral over $\theta$ by an integral over $z$. (the correct answer should be $-6i$)

Comment: Hello achille hui, can you please write an explicit solution and/or explanation. I would really appreciate it. The steps are long and tedious and I can't seem to figure out where I am making a mistake. Thank you. If you want me to write out my process more clearly, please let me know.

Comment: Hmm, I missed a $\pi$ in my previous comment, should be $-6\pi i$. If you insists to start you integral at $\theta = -\pi/4$ and end at $\theta = \pi/4$, then you need to cut you contour at negative real axis. i.e. you integrate from $-\pi/4$ to $-\pi$ and then from $\pi$ to $\pi/4$.

Comment: I understand. I got the same answer! However, I cannot get $6i\pi$ when I use Green's Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}$
$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$
$\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}$
$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$

Let $\zeta^s=\e^{\i \pi s/4}$, $\zeta = \zeta^1$.

Write $I$ for $[0,1]$.
$$\begin{align}
f_0 &: I \to \C & f_0(t) &= 2\zeta^{-1}t \\
f_1 &: I \to \C & f_1(t) &= 2\zeta^{-1-2t} \\
f_2 &: I \to \C & f_2(t) &= 2\zeta t\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Write $C_i$ for the image of $f_i$. Then

$$\gamma = C_0 + C_1 + C_2\text{.}$$

Note that $\bar{z}=-\i z$ on $C_0$, $\bar{z}=4/z$ on $C_1$, and $\bar{z}=\i z$ on $C_2$. Then

$$\begin{split}
\int_{\gamma}\bar{z}\d z
  &= \int_{C_0}\bar{z}\d z
   + \int_{C_1}\bar{z}\d z
   + \int_{C_2}\bar{z}\d z \\
  &= -\i \int_{C_0}z\d z
   + 4 \int_{C_1}\frac{\d z}{z}
   + \i \int_{C_2}z \d z \\
  &= -\i \int_0^{2\zeta^{-1}} z \d z
   + 4\i \int_{-\pi/4}^{-7\pi/4}\d\theta
   + \i \int_{2\zeta}^0 z \d z \\
  &= \left.-\i\frac{z^2}{2}\right\rvert_{z=0}^{2\zeta^{-1}}
   + 4\i \left.\theta\right\rvert_{\theta=-\pi/4}^{-7\pi/4}
   + \left.\i\frac{z^2}{2}\right\rvert_{z=2\zeta}^{0} \\
  &= -2\i\zeta^{-2}
   - 6\pi \i
   - 2\i\zeta^2 \\
  &= -6\pi\i
\end{split}$$

---

Using Green's theorem to convert to an area integral: write A for the region whose boundary is $-\gamma$. Then

$$\begin{split}
\int_{\gamma}\bar{z}\d z
  &= -\int_A \d\bar{z}\wedge \d z\\
  &= -2\i\int_A \d x\wedge \d y \\
  &= -2\i\lvert A\rvert \\
  &= -2\i(3\pi) \\
  &= -6\pi \i\text{.}
\end{split}$$